# Input 0 of layer "block1_conv1_bn" is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=4, found ndim=5. Full shape received: (None, None, 149, 149, 32)

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I have the following code:

```
from src.objects.image_handler import ImageHandler
from src.objects.caption_handler import CaptionHandler
from src.objects.data_handler import DataHandler
from src.models.captioner_model import CaptionerModel
import tensorflow as tf
import pickle
import os

if __name__ == "__main__":

    image_handler = ImageHandler(
        folder_path="data/test", dimensions=(299, 299), preprocess_function=tf.keras.applications.xception.preprocess_input)
    
    caption_handler = CaptionHandler(
        filenames=image_handler.filenames, filepath="data/test.txt")
    
    data_handler = DataHandler(image_handler, caption_handler)

    train_generator, val_generator = data_handler.get_generators(batch_size=1)

    for batch in train_generator:
        print(f"Image batch shape: {batch[0].shape}")
        print(f"Importance factor batch shape: {batch[1].shape}")
        print(f"Caption batch shape: {batch[2].shape}")

    captioner_model = CaptionerModel(
        max_length=caption_handler.max_length,
        vocabulary_size=len(caption_handler.tokenizer.word_index) + 1,
        height=299,
        width=299)
    
    captioner_model.compile(
        optimizer="adam", loss="sparse_categorical_crossentropy", run_eagerly=True)
    
    captioner_model.fit(
        train_generator,
        epochs=10,
        validation_data=val_generator)
```

where the print statements output the following:

```
Image batch shape: (1, 299, 299, 3)
Importance factor batch shape: (1, 2048)
Caption batch shape: (1, 19)
```

My model is as follows:

```
"""
This module defines the CaptionerModel class, which contains the Encoder-Decoder model and the methods for training, evaluating and making inference with it.
The model is made up of:
Input:
    - an image, which is fed to an Xception model to extract its features, which is a (None, 2048) array
    - Importance Factor features, which are (None, 2048) arrays
    - a caption, which is a vector of integers representing the words in the caption of length max_length
Hidden layers:
    - A concatenation of the image features and the Importance Factor features
    - An embedding layer, which converts the caption into a (None, 256) array
    - An AdditiveAttention layer, which is used to calculate the context vector
    - A GRU layer, which is used to generate the output sequence
    - Two Dense layers, which are used to calculate the probability distribution over the vocabulary
Output:
    - A sequence of words, which is the predicted caption for the image
"""

import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input, Embedding, GRU, Dense, Concatenate, AdditiveAttention
from tensorflow.keras.applications import Xception
import sys

class CaptionerModel(tf.keras.Model):

    def __init__(self, max_length, vocabulary_size, height, width):
        super(CaptionerModel, self).__init__()

        # Define input layers
        self.image_input = Input(shape=(None, height, width, 3))
        self.importance_factor_input = Input(shape=(None, 2048))
        self.caption_input = Input(shape=(None, max_length))

        # Use Xception for image feature extraction
        xception_model = Xception(include_top=False, weights='imagenet', pooling='avg')
        xception_model.trainable = False
        image_features = xception_model(self.image_input)

        # Concatenate image features and importance factor features
        concatenated_features = Concatenate(axis=-1)([image_features, self.importance_factor_input])

        # Embedding layer for captions
        caption_embedding = Embedding(input_dim=vocabulary_size, output_dim=256)(self.caption_input)

        # Calculate context vector using AdditiveAttention
        context_vector = AdditiveAttention()([concatenated_features, caption_embedding])

        # GRU layer for sequence generation
        gru_layer = GRU(256, return_sequences=True)(context_vector)

        # Dense layers for generating the probability distribution over vocabulary
        self.output_probabilities = Dense(vocabulary_size, activation='softmax')(gru_layer)

    def call(self, inputs):
        image_input = inputs[0]
        importance_factor_input = inputs[1]
        caption_input = inputs[2]

        tf.print("image_input", image_input, output_stream=sys.stderr)
        tf.print("importance_factor_input", importance_factor_input, output_stream=sys.stderr)
        tf.print("caption_input", caption_input, output_stream=sys.stderr)

        return self.output_probabilities
```

As far as i'm concerned, the input shape on the images matches that expected by Xception, and yet i always get the error:

```
Input 0 of layer "block1_conv1_bn" is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=4, found ndim=5. Full shape received: (None, None, 149, 149, 32)
```

I'd also like to ask why the print statement inside of the call function do not output anything